# Reassigning the value of a StaticResource in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm loading data from a file and want to assign it to the View. I'm using a StaticResource binding type in the XAML, because it's easier to navigate within it when defining the View.

How do I reassign the value of the StaticResource defined in XAML to the data I just loaded?

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Container x:Key="Container"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="Combo" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Container}}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class Container : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    public Container()
    {
        Add("AAA");
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Container resource = FindResource("Container") as Container;

        Container container2 = new Container() { "BBB" };

        resource = container2;
    }
}
```

Here, the Combobox is supposed to have "AAA" and "BBB", but the code-behind does not change it. I cannot set it to DynamicResource and using INotifyPropertyChanged interface doesn't help.

Of course doing `Combo.ItemsSource = container2;` works, but it then forces me to set all the bindings of the View elements in the code-behind. And how would I then set the RelativeSource bindings for all the child elements that need data from the top levels of the class hierarchy, i.e. now I can do `{Binding Source={StaticResource Container}, Path=TopClass.AnotherCollection.Value}` within a child element.

Comment: if you want to assign data to view, use DataContext property. WPF bindings are tuned to it. and it can be easily changed in runtime. for design-times intellisense support use design-time datacontext ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48966829/1506454))

Comment: @ASh How would I then bind child elements that need the data from somewhere besides the parent's DataContext? Would RelativeSource make sense or do I have to set all those bindings in code?

Comment: if you want detailed answer, you should provide more details yourself in the first place. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would replace the actual resource with another `Container` instance:

```
this.Resources["Container"] = container2;
```

But doing this won't affect the `ComboBox` unless you use a `DynamicResource` in your XAML markup:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo" 
          ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Container}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The value of a `StaticResource` markup extension is only resolved once.

Comment: @deadfish: Did you try this?